# How to fix index out of range

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have the following code. and I keep geting an error "Index out of range when I purposely enter the wrong combox productnumber.   "index out of range here.... ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += (txtPriceAmount.Text * txtQuantityAmount.Text)"

this only does this after I click the combobox down arrow to pull in the right number but then backspace to change it to be wrong. otherwise when I start the program and enter the numbers manually into combox in validates and works fine. Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
  Private Sub PurchaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles PurchaseToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'Test to determine if a product was found.
    If txtDescription.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cannot purchase, product was not found
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid product before purchasing.", "Cannot Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        txtProductID.Focus()
        txtProductID.SelectAll()
    Else
        'Can purchase the product
        'Build a string to display in the listbox control

        Dim ProductString As String = txtProductID.Text.PadRight(12, " ") & "" & txtDescription.Text.PadRight(50, " ") & "" & txtQuantityAmount.Text.PadRight(7, " ") & "" & txtPriceAmount.Text.PadLeft(9, " ").ToString
        lstPurchaseItems.Items.Add(ProductString).ToString()
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Accumulate the total value of this customer order
        'and display it to the output textbox
        TotalDueDecimal += (txtPriceAmount.Text.ToString * txtQuantityAmount.Text)
        txtTotalDueAmount.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")
        'TotalDueTextBox.Text = QuantityTextBox.Text * TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


        'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
        Dim IndexInteger As Integer = cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex
        ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += (txtPriceAmount.Text * txtQuantityAmount.Text)

        'Here you can clear the form of product info if you think
        'that is a good way to do the processing
        cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex = -1
        txtProductID.Clear()
        txtDescription.Clear()
        txtPriceAmount.Clear()
        txtQuantityAmount.Clear()
        txtProductID.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what line throws the exception?

Comment: Is an item selected in the `ComboBox` at `cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex`? Otherwise you get that exception at the next line at `ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger)`.

Comment: if you change the contents of the text portion "to be wrong" then `cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex` will be -1, test for that before capturing the value

Comment: You are defining IndexInteger on a account of one ComboBox (cboProductIDLookup) and applying it to a different one (ProductSalesTotalDecimal). If both comboboxes do not have the same number of elements, this would be what is provoking your problem. Also bear in mind that you can do cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex = -1 but if you apply a -1 while dealing with items it would also create an error (and you are using this index precisely). There are various not-too-good parts which might be provoking the problem, but without the exact inputs it is difficult to tell which one.

Comment: the easy fix is to just set the combobox property to dropdown list. When I do this the problem is resolved, but for sake of learning I would like to know how to fix the program error

Comment: I'm wondering how many questions you'll be able to ask using the exact same code as example: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338524/how-to-set-format-for-currency. If you want to gat quality answers, take some time editing your code, extracting the relevant part and getting rid of the rest. My .02€ tip...

Comment: As always, please include a reduced test case for your problem. You are much more likely to get a quick answer after that.

Answer (score 1):

```
  'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
  Dim IndexInteger As Integer = cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex
```

There is no 'program error' simply a condition you did not account for.  If the control list DropDowntype is set to DropDown you can pick something from the list OR type something in.  In some apps, typing in something new makes that item get added to the datasource.

In that case, or when the user 'enters a wrong' value, the combo.SelectedIndex will be -1.  This is by design and is easy to test for:

```
   ' you missed this 
   If cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
      ' Post error/warning message
      ' or
      ' add new item
      ' as appropritate
   End If
```

In some apps it simply is not feasible to list every possible option in the list, so only the top likely options are listed.  The user can type in something altogether different as a perfectly valid option.  In an add new item type app, a SelectedIndex of -1 is the signal to do so.

As you belatedly discovered you can have the combo box work in Limit-to-list fashion meaning the user cannot enter a value not in the list.  This is not a fix, but a different operational mode or style.    This operational mode is not appropriate for the two other use cases described above.

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation would be to always compare lengths before analyzing.

You have 2x combo boxes, each with a variable size.

Try the following idea:

```
if ((Combobox1.SelectedIndex <= (Combobox2.Items.Count - 1)) and 
(Combobox2.SelectedIndex <= (Combobox1.Items.Count - 1))) then
   //operation
else
   //error
end if
```

Alternitively, put some *throw*...*catch* statements.