# How to set format for currency

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I think I have finnaly found my answer to different question but the program doest like any of my formats with this following code. I need to format this line:

`Dim ProductString As String = txtProductID.Text.PadRight(12, " ") & "" & txtDescription.Text.PadRight(50, " ") & "" & txtQuantityAmount.Text.PadRight(7, " ") & "" & txtPriceAmount.Text.PadLeft(9, " ").ToString`

Specifically, I need `txtPriceAmount.Text.PadLeft(9, " ").ToString` to accept currency Format ("C2"). What am I doing wrong??

```
  Private Sub PurchaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles PurchaseToolStripMenuItem.Click

    'Test to determine if a product was found.
    If txtDescription.Text = String.Empty Then

        'Cannot purchase, product was not found
        MessageBox.Show("You must select a valid product before purchasing.", "Cannot Purchase", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        txtProductID.Focus()
        txtProductID.SelectAll()
    Else
        'Can purchase the product

        Dim ProductString As String = txtProductID.Text.PadRight(12, " ") & "" & txtDescription.Text.PadRight(50, " ") & "" & txtQuantityAmount.Text.PadRight(7, " ") & "" & txtPriceAmount.Text.PadLeft(9, " ").ToString
        lstPurchaseItems.Items.Add(ProductString)
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'Accumulate the total value of this customer order
        'and display it to the output textbox
        TotalDueDecimal += (txtPriceAmount.Text.ToString * txtQuantityAmount.Text)
        txtTotalDueAmount.Text = TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")
        'TotalDueTextBox.Text = QuantityTextBox.Text * TotalDueDecimal.ToString("C2")

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


        'Accumulate total sales by product to an array
        Dim IndexInteger As Integer = cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex
        ProductSalesTotalDecimal(IndexInteger) += (txtPriceAmount.Text * txtQuantityAmount.Text)

        'Here you can clear the form of product info if you think
        'that is a good way to do the processing
        cboProductIDLookup.SelectedIndex = -1
        txtProductID.Clear()
        txtDescription.Clear()
        txtPriceAmount.Clear()
        txtQuantityAmount.Clear()
        txtProductID.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if I change to ("C2") I get this error.  Conversion from string "C2" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Comment: How about posting code that is legible and which compiles? I can't even reformat what you posted since I don't know what all the "...." means

Comment: a way to clarify the question to be able to read it. Code in the blue box compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `txtPriceAmount.Text` to a number, then format it as currency:

```
Double.Parse(txtPriceAmount.Text).ToString("C2").PadLeft(9, " ")
```

You'll get an error if txtPriceAmount.Text isn't numeric.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have been working on that simple solution for days. Textbox only accepts numerical input with automatic decimal placement and rights form right to left. Thanks a bunch

Comment: I have a problem pecause the price cant be 00.00 either. Throws exception unhandeled. How would I fix this